# Android Context not serializable dilemma for class that implements Iteratable

Tags: java, android, serialization

Here is my situation. I have written a Playlist class that stores a context. Playlist has 9 child classes. Unfortunately, to pass Playlist between intents, it must implement Serializable. This is a problem because Playlist stores a context, so that the Iterator can work, as the Iterator method that must be Overridden from Iterator can not accept any parameters. Therefore, I must store Context *somewhere* as it is needed to determine the size of the Playlist. Here is the (simplified) code.

```
public abstract class Playlist implements Serializable, Iterable<Song>
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

        private Context context;
        public Context getContext() { return context; }

        public Playlist(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public abstract int size(); //getContext() referenced in all currently written children
        public abstract Song getSong(int index); //getContext() referenced in all currently written children

        @Override
        public PlaylistIterator iterator()
        {
            return new PlaylistIterator();
        }

        public class PlaylistIterator implements Iterator<Song>
        {
            private int current;

            PlaylistIterator()
            {
                current = 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext()
            {
                return current < size(); //SIZE HERE needs access to a context, but this method certainly can not take one, and neither can the constructor above.**
            }

            @Override
            public Song next()
            {
                if (!hasNext())
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();

                return getSong(current++);
            }

            @Override
            public void remove()
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have read that you *can* store a static context, but that this is poor design. I can not seem to find a way around this.

I have considered adding a static context reference that is assigned in writeObject, and then accessed in readObject, as the transition should be nearly instant because the Serialization implementation is only so that Playlist can be passed in an intent. But even this feels hacky.

Is there a common work around to dealing with the fact that we cannot serialize context? Is my solution acceptable in terms of stability? It might be against the rules, but what is your recommendation in this situation?

Comment: Try to separate logic from data. Then you could just send the data without the issue you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have written a Playlist class that stores a context

That's probably not a good idea.

> Unfortunately, to pass Playlist between intents, it must implement Serializable

It could be `Parcelable`, but that does not solve your problem. A `Context` cannot go into either a `Serializable` or a `Parcelable`.

> because Playlist stores a context, so that the Iterator can work,

That's probably not a good idea.

> Therefore, I must store Context somewhere as it is needed to determine the size of the Playlist.

Or, the `Playlist` could hold the size of the playlist. An `int` is readily able to be used with `Serializable` or `Parcelable`.

Or, get rid of the `Iterator`, as that is not going to work well with `Serializable` or `Parcelable` either.

> I can not seem to find a way around this.

Have `Playlist` be a pure model object, with no `Context`.

Or, depending on the use case, have `Playlist` be a singleton, using the `Application` as the `Context`. It is unclear whether there is only one `Playlist` or several.

> but what is your recommendation in this situation?

`Playlist` should not hold a `Context` and should not have an `Iterator`.

Comment: Unfortunately the playlist size can not be determined in the constructor. It is read from the size of cursor, and is not generated until it is needed.